# Is there an alternative to "that much less"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

> The teams weren't fair to begin with, but Jim's injury made them *that much less fair*.

The last part of that sentence feels wrong to me due to the contrast of "much" and "less". Is there perhaps a more natural sounding alternative to convey the same meaning without rephrasing the sentence entirely?

Comment: Sounds fine to me, [being -> begin aside].  You can replace *that much* with *even* however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- all the more unfair
- even worse
- that much more unbalanced
- more unfair still

They still feel kind of awkward though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

> The teams weren't fair to begin with, but Jim's injury made them **still less** fair.

or, to avoid repeating *fair*:

> The teams weren't equal to begin with, but Jim's injury made them still less fair.

or even

> The teams weren't equal to begin with, but Jim's injury made them unfairer still.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is considered rephrasing, but I think the culprit is the weak verb "made":

> The teams weren't fair to begin with,
>   but Jim's injury exposed their
>   treachery.

or

> The teams weren't fair to begin with,
>   but Jim's injury brought them to a new low.